# Run Tortoise SVN client from Java

Tags: java, tortoisesvn

I need to call Tortoise SVN client from Java applications. In fact I have entire control of SVN client from Java. The application must be aware of the results of the execution of operations.

Does anyone know if it can be performed safely?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You might want to use a SVN client library like [SVNKit](http://www.svnkit.com) instead of trying to control tortoiseSVN.